# What am I doing wrong? Freecodecamp portfolio

Tags: html

I'm doing a freeCodeCamp portfolio but I keep failing one test:

> 10. Additionally, the navbar should contain link (`<a>` elements with the class of `nav-link`. There should be one for every element with
>     the class `main-section`.

```
  <nav id= "navbar">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <header id= "title">JS Documentation</header>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Introduction">Introduction</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#JavaScript_and_Java">JavaScript and Java</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Hello_world">Hello World</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Variables">Variables</a>
  <a  class="nav-link"href="#Declaring_variables">Declaring variables</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Variable_scope">Variable Scope</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Global_variables">Global Variables</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Constants">Constants</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Data_types">Data types</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#If...else_statements">If else statements</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Reference">References</a>     
        
</div>
</nav>
```

https://codepen.io/Sharoze111/pen/wvMNyQw?editors=1010

Here is the link to the CodePen and you can run the test 'technical documentation page' within the link (3 green bars).

It's something to do with the nav-links not linking to the ID's but I can't find the issue.

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly what's the issue(error)?

Comment: Hey, if you click on the link it will open a codepen, in the top left you can click on 3 bars which open a test menu. If you select the test 'Technical documentation page' and then click run tests, it will say 15/16 tests passed. If you click on 'tests 15/16' it will give you more information on the test thats being failed (the one in the description above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more verbose error message from the test was: `AssertionError: There should be one .nav-link for every element with the class of "main-section", and every .nav-link should be within #navbar : expected 11 to equal 9`

If you look closely, only 9 of your `section` elements have the class `main-section`. Two of them erroneously have `main_section` as the class.

Comment: Thanks. I Just fixed that but now i'm presented with:  `Check that these headers have corresponding .nav-link elements and be mindful of case! : IF...ELSE STATEMENTS,REFERENCE : expected 2 to equal 0
AssertionError: Check that these headers have corresponding .nav-link elements and be mindful of case! : IF...ELSE STATEMENTS,REFERENCE : expected 2 to equal 0`

Comment: The error message says it all: the text in your link should match the header text in the section. You forgot the ellipses in `If...else_statements` and made `Reference` plural when it should have been singular.

Comment: ahhhh! I didn't know the actual text has to match the link too. Thanks for that.